# Apico-alveolar consonants in Romagnol Italian and certain accents of Chinese: is that a thing?

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation

Once upon a time were me and my brother, spending time at my grandma's in Romagna. We discovered she pronounced /ʃ/ almost like /s/, and even made fun of that by having her say «Schubert, Schumann e Chopin scioperavano» (IPA /'ʃu.bert 'ʃu.man e ʃo'pɛn ʃo.pe'ra.va.no/, translates to «Schubert, Schumann and Chopin went on strikes»). Another joke that arose from this pronunciation defect, which was shared with grandpa (and I guess is widespread enough among older people of the area, that is of Russi and neighboring towns) was «Perché ci sono i s(c)emi? Perché non tutti sono intelligenti» (Why are there seeds/idiots? Because not everyone is intelligent – semi /'se.mi/ = seeds, scemi /'ʃe.mi/ = idiots).

Later on, I was trying to explain to my dad what a retroflex consonant is in the context of teaching him Mandarin pronunciation, and he compared it to that pseudo-/ʃ/ we made fun of, and I thought «Yep, that's it».

Recently, I was randomly reading about [the readjustment of sibilants in Old Spanish](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reajuste_de_las_sibilantes_del_idioma_espa%C3%B1ol) (Spanish article), and I tried producing an apico-alveolar consonant, and I was like «Oh, maybe grandma actually had /s̺/ (apico-alveolar), not /ʂ/, as I previously thought.

> How widespread is this mispronunciation of /ʃ/ among old people in Romagna, and is it a retroflex or an apico-alveolar consonant?

But it doesn't end there. Recently, I was re-listening to [this Hakka song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RH7wfVu72zk), and I thought I noticed a number of sibilants in the singer's pronunciation, going from plain lamino-alveolar /s̻/ to alveolo-palatal /ɕ/ to some other sibilant which sounded like – wait for it… here it comes… – apico-alveolar /s̺/. So here comes another two questions. Firstly:

> Is it possible that some Hakka dialects actually contrast apico-alveolar and lamino-alveolar, with any one of those or perhaps both palatalizing to alveolo-palatals in front of /i/?

And secondly, I thought of those Chinese people who seem to mispronounced retroflexes as alveolars.

> Is it possible that at least in some cases the distinction is there but it is not perceived by others because retroflexes become apico-alveolar and alveolars stay as lamino-alveolars?